# Prestashop: cannot redeclare class AdminImportControllerCore

Tags: php, csv, import, prestashop

I have an online shop with Prestashop 1.5.4.1 and I would like to use a script to update products and other data. This is the script (relevant part):

```
define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
include(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/../config/config.inc.php');
include(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/functions.php');
include_once '../controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php';

$import = New AdminImportControllerCore();
switch($_GET['entity']) {
    case 0:
        loadCategoriesPost();
        $import->categoryImport();
        break;
    case 1:
        loadProductsPost();
        $import->productImport();
        break;
    ...
}

function loadCategoriesPost() {
    ...
}

function loadProductsPost() {
    ...
}
```

When the call to $import->productImport() is made, this error occurs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class AdminImportControllerCore in /var/www/shop/controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php
```

Anyone can help me? Is there a better way than this in order to import CSV data (not using import tool from Prestashop admin panel)? I'm stuck at this point.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try leaving `Core` suffix when creating instance of `AdminImportController`. Btw. correct is: `$import = new AdminImportController();` with small "n" at `new`.

Comment: remove the core, and also try to remove the include statement for the AdminImportControllerCore, may be it works

Answer (score 0):

first of all don't include the controllers or classes from presta, they will be auto loaded,
second, don't call classes with suffix, remove "Core",
third, stop using instances of controllers as above, You should make a code getting instances of classes not controller, so if you need a import try to check what code is in $import->categoryImport(); method, then you will see ( or not ), that you can do it without controller.

regards adn sorry for my English